Get frequency of specific transition in graph
In a chain there are 3 different states: ST, GRC_i and GRC_j.
The following edges between the states exists:
EDGES = [
    # source, target,  name
    ('ST',    'GRC_i', 'TDL_i'),
    ('ST',    'GRC_j', 'TDL_j'),
    ('GRC_i', 'GRC_j', 'RVL_j'),
    ('GRC_j', 'GRC_i', 'RVL_i'),
    ('GRC_j', 'ST',    'SUL_i'),
    ('GRC_i', 'ST',    'SUL_j'),

]

The graph looks as follows:

The values for TDL_i, TDL_i, RVL_i and RVL_j are known.
The chain always starts in ST.
If RVL_i = RVL_j = 0 then SUL_i is equal to max(0, TDL_i - 1).
Is is possible to infer SUL_i and SUL_j for other scenarios?
